# TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null karma using Karma

Tags: angular, typescript, karma-jasmine, karma-runner, angular6

I have seen many questions about this error but none of them have helped me to find the source of the problem, how do I know where this error comes from and how do I fix it?

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null
at HttpHeaders.applyUpdate (webpack:///./node_modules/@angular/common/fesm5/http.js?:235:27)
at eval (webpack:///./node_modules/@angular/common/fesm5/http.js?:206:74)
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at HttpHeaders.init (webpack:///./node_modules/@angular/common/fesm5/http.js?:206:33)
at HttpHeaders.forEach (webpack:///./node_modules/@angular/common/fesm5/http.js?:271:14)
at Observable.eval [as _subscribe] (webpack:///./node_modules/@angular/common/fesm5/http.js?:1481:25)
at Observable._trySubscribe (webpack:///./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js?:48:25)
at Observable.subscribe (webpack:///./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js?:34:22)
at eval (webpack:///./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/util/subscribeTo.js?:33:31)
at subscribeToResult (webpack:///./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/util/subscribeToResult.js?:10:84)
at ____________________Elapsed_26_ms__At__Tue_Sep_04_2018_11_58_19_GMT_0200__hora_de_verano_de_Europa_central_ (http://localhost)
at Object.onScheduleTask (webpack:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js?:107:22)
at ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask (webpack:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js?:400:51)
at Object.onScheduleTask (webpack:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js?:296:29)
at ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask (webpack:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js?:400:51)
at Zone.scheduleTask (webpack:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js?:231:43)
at Zone.scheduleMacroTask (webpack:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js?:254:25)
at scheduleMacroTaskWithCurrentZone (webpack:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js?:1113:25)
at eval (webpack:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js?:2089:28)
```

The error can be seen both in the browser console (Chrome) and when launching tests with Karma.

Another failed test message shows the following:

```
[object ErrorEvent] thrown
```

I don't know how to track this bug either.

UPDATE: Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example

Service:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Country } from '../countries/country.model';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Configuration } from '../../constants';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DropdownService {

    private server: String;

    constructor(
        private http: HttpClient,
        private configuration: Configuration
    ) {
        this.server = this.configuration.serverOCD;
    }

    getCountries(): Observable<Country[]> {
        return this.http.get<Country[]>(this.server + '/api/v1/country');
    }
}
```

Component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

import { DropdownService } from '../services/dropdown.service';
import { Country } from './country.model';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
    selector: 'dropdown-countries',
    templateUrl: './countries.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./countries.component.css']
})

export class CountriesComponent implements OnInit {

    countries$: Observable<Country[]>;
    countries: Country[] = [];
    countriesForm: FormGroup;
    country: FormControl;

    constructor(
        private fb: FormBuilder,
        private dropdownService: DropdownService,
    ) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.countriesForm = this.fb.group({
            country: this.fb.control(new Country().code = '')
        });

        // 1st try
        this.getCountries();

        // 2nd try
        this.countries$ = this.dropdownService.getCountries();
    }

    getCountries() {
        this.dropdownService.getCountries().subscribe(
            data => this.countries = data,
            err => console.error(err),
            () => console.log('done loading countries')
        );
    }

}
```

Template:

```
<div [formGroup]="countriesForm">
    <select id="countriesDropdown" class="form-control form-control-sm" formControlName="country">
        <option value="" disabled>Choose a Country</option>
        <option *ngFor="let country of countries$ | async" [ngValue]="country">{{country.longDescription}}</option>
    </select>
</div>
<p>Form value: {{ countriesForm.value | json }}</p>
```

Comment: We're going to need a [mcve] or some context in order to help you.

Comment: `getCountries()` is asynchronous so if you are checking `this.countries.length` somewhere, either initialize it as default with an empty array, or check if `this.countries` is actually available. I don't think that the code you have shown really has the bug itself

Comment: @Icepickle I don't check the length of countries anywhere, I must be missing something, is it necessary to set the headers for this request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after 2 days of research, I've managed to find the problem, and it comes from this code I didn't think would influence:

GenericService:

```
@Injectable()
export class JWTInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

    private token: string;

    constructor(
        private config: Configuration,
        private authStore: AuthenticationStore
    ) { }

    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

        this.token = this.authStore.getToken();

        if (!req.headers.has('Content-Type')) {
            req = req.clone({ headers: req.headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json') });
        }

        req = req.clone({ headers: req.headers.set('Accept', 'application/json') });
        req = req.clone({ headers: req.headers.set('Authorization', this.token) });

        return next.handle(req);
    }
}
```

SharedModule:

```
providers: [
    GenericService,
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: JWTInterceptor,
      multi: true,
    }
],
```

With these snippets, all the request were being intercepted by JWTInterceptor, which it was throwing the error and I didn't want, so I used `HttpBackend` to ignore that interceptor:

DropdownService:

```
constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    private handler: HttpBackend, // to ignore interceptor
    private configuration: Configuration
) {
    this.http = new HttpClient(this.handler); // use it in HttpClient
    this.server = this.configuration.serverOCD;
}
```